# What is the default version of a POM project?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

If I do not include an explicit ***version*** tag, in a POM.xml file, and this file is a child module. What version will this be?

It seems to be the same version as the parent module, but is this a good practice considering I'm trying to start using versions-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the version is inherited. And whether it is a good practice, it depends. If you have a multi-module project but all the modules have a single lifecycle (i.e. you never release one of the modules on its own, only the whole project) then it does make sense to have only a central version tag in the parent and let the submodules inherit it. One disadvantage of this approach is that you will be releasing new versions of modules that didn't change. So the code between submodule-1.0.0 and submodule-1.0.1 might be exactly the same, which IMO is kind of a pain to deal with for tech support and long term maintenance.

If on the other hand, your versioning policy is to increment a submodule version only when its code changes, then having a central version inherited is not good and each submodule should define its own version

Comment: Well, it is already a nightmare to maintain :) We will start releasing  all projects as a whole even if they did no change. But since we have an obfuscation step, it forces us to anyway. Thx.